# schedule a task by "AT" command

Tags: windows, cmd

I tried to schedule a program by 'at' command in cmd. Some programs like 'php' worked well, but program that using gui like notepad, mspaint didn't work.

I want to know the solution or why it doesn't work. Thanks for reading.

Comment: have you tried schtasks /?

Comment: Here is more info that you may need in modern versions of Windows: http://serverfault.com/questions/251733/task-scheduler-runs-as-hidden-how-to-make-it-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

schtasks is the recommended method, and replacement for AT command.